# Why can a type-specifier be considered as a qualified-id when used in a template declaration

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

```cpp
template<typename T>
void fun(){
  T::type v;  
}
```

In this example, `T::type` is considered as an expression. The relevant rule is stated in the current draft, that is:
[temp.res#general-5](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#general-5)

> A **qualified-id** whose terminal name is dependent and that is in a type-only context is considered to denote a type.

In my mind, for `T::type v` where `T::type` shouldn't be considered as an expression anyhow. Because according to the whole section [expr](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr), That's not possible to be an expression if obey the grammars listed in [expr].

In this case, `T::type` should be considered as a simple-type-specifier that has the form `nested-name-specifier opt type-name`. At least, it's a type-specifier rather than a `qualified-id`. So, I wonder how does [temp.res#general-5] apply to this example, the precondition of that rule is that the component should be first a **qualified-id**.

As contrast, the following example is a bit difference

```cpp
template<typename T>
void fun(){
   T::type * v;
}
```

For `T::type* v`, according to the grammar of [expr], `T::type` can be considered as a qualified-id. It also can be considered as a type-specifier as per [declaration]. It's underspecified in the standard to specify how to resolve the ambiguity for a statement that appeared in a template declaration(Whether a qualified name is considered as a qualified-id or some components that look like a qualified-id, such as a simple-type-specifier).

As aforementioned, The rule [temp.res#general-5] does not cover these components that used to form a statement and cannot be considered a qualified-id if it obeys the corresponding valid grammar. So, how to interpret these questions?

Comment: [The previous paragraph](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#general-4) defines the term "type-only context". `T::type v;` is not one of those.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Do you mean these qualified names that are not in type-only context are all considered as qualified-id regardless of whether such a decision can make the grammar be valid?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My  confusion is  that although a declt-specifier is not in the type-only context, it still cannot be called a qualified-id, Right?

Comment: A name of the form `Name1::Name2::...::NameN` is a *qualified-id*. That's simply a syntactical construct. The question is that of semantics: whether that name denotes a type or something else. This is important because the meaning of things like `A*B` depend on whether `A` is a type. Usually, the nature of the entity denoted by the name can be determined from the declaration of that name - but not for dependent names in a template. For those, the name is presumed to be not-a-type unless in a *type-only context*. One can always put the name into such a context by prepending `typename` keyword.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik *A name of the form Name1::Name2::...::NameN is a qualified-id.*, if it were,  a simple-type-specifier with the form `Name1::Name2::...::NameN` would be a qualified-id? In my mind, it's just a  type-specifier in the grammar. Although a qualified-id and a simple-type-specifier all can have a form, which is the form that an identifier follows a `nested-name-specifier`, however, they're the different syntax.(one is called simple-type-specifier, the other is called **qualified-id**)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66407140/is-it-the-intent-of-the-standard-that-any-form-nested-type-specifier-followed-b) is a simplified question for here.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. C++ grammar is not context-free: syntax and semantics are interdependent. In the grammar, *qualified-id* is a form of *id-expression*, only used for names that are not-types; while *simple-type-specifier* is used for types. But syntactically, they look the same: `Name1::Name2` could be *qualified-id* if it refers to a non-type, or *simple-type-specifier* if it refers to a type; the grammar is ambiguous. To disambiguate, it is necessary to consider context. (continued)

Comment: Usually, the compiler would perform name lookups for each component, find the corresponding declaration, figure out whether the rightmost name refers to a type, then take it as either *qualified-id* or *simple-type-specifier* and continue parsing accordingly. But in a template, when it encounters a dependent name, it cannot complete name lookup. To break this impasse, it's necessary to disambiguate based on syntactical clues alone. So the standard introduces a rule - a dependent name is to be assumed a non-type unless it appears in *type-only context*. (continued)

Comment: I agree this rule is somewhat inartfully stated - calling such a name a *qualified-id* is kinda begging the question. The standard lacks the formal term for "a name that matches the grammar production of *qualified-id*, but for which it's not yet clear whether it refers to a type and so should be treated as *simple-type-specifier*, or a non-type treated as *qualified-id*". **[temp.res]/5** uses *qualified-id* in this sense.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah, you get my doubt here. The core issue for this question is that [temp.res]/5 should not use the `qualified-id` to intend to cover any notation with the form `nested-name-specifier identifier`, which are not  **qualified-id** in the grammar. I think `qualified name` is an alternative as per [basic.lookup.qual#general-2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual#general-2). However, as figured out in my other question, `simple-type-specifier` is lacked in the list in which the name can be called a qualified name.(continued)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  In addition, I don't find the rule that says "a dependent name is to be assumed a non-type" in the current [draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/)

Comment: **[temp.res]/5** is that rule. Again, perhaps not stated very clearly, but that's the intent, in my humble opinion.