# Is it the intent of the standard that any form `nested-type-specifier followed by an identifier` can be called a qualified-id

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This is a simplified question derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66405918/why-can-a-type-specifier-be-considered-as-a-qualified-id-when-used-in-a-template)

```cpp
struct A{
  using type = int;
};
int main(){
  A::type variable;  //#1
}
```

For the declaration at `#1`, it's consisted of a type-specifier and a declarator. In more detail, the type-specifier is a simple-type-specifier that has the form:
[dcl.type.simple](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple)

> nested-name-specifier <sub>opt</sub> type-name

Usually, the name `type` is a qualified name that should be lookup in the scope of `A`. However, the following rules do not say so.
[basic.lookup.qual#general-2.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual#general-2.4)

> A qualified name is
>
> - a member-qualified name or
> - the terminal name of
>
>   - a qualified-id,
>   - a using-declarator
>   - a typename-specifier
>   - a qualified-namespace-specifier, or
>   - a nested-name-specifier, elaborated-type-specifier, or class-or-decltype that has a nested-name-specifier ([expr.prim.id.qual]).

The list does not mention the **simple-type-specifier** which has the form `nested-name-specifier type-name`. I don't know whether the rule intends to use `qualified-id` to cover this case(I'm not sure). If it is, I have to say a `simple-type-specifer` is not a `qualified-id`, although they all can have the form, which is a nested-type-specifier followed by an identifier. In my mind, a `qualified-id` is designated by the grammar which comprises a `qualified-id`. For example

> postfix-expression . template<sub>opt</sub> id-expression

Where the `id-expression` might be a `qualified-id`. In this case, the notation that appears in the `id-expression` which has the form `nested-name-specifier identifier` is called a qualified-id(i.e, what can it be called is designated by the grammar).

A simple-type-specifier that has the form `nested-name-specifier identifier` has a different syntactic meaning with a qualified-id that has the same form. At least, a simple-type-specifier cannot be called a `qualified-id` **since we cannot find the syntax `qualified-id` in the grammar tree of the type-specifier**. Similar things are so many somewhere in the standard(such as the aforementioned question). Is it a defect of the standard(It intends to use `qualified-id` to cover other notations that have the form `nested-name-specifier identifier`)?

Answer (score 0):

It could be argued that this is an omission, but until name lookup takes place it’s not generally possible to know whether *nested-name-specifier* *identifier* is a *simple-type-specifier* or a *qualified-id*.  The rule is written in terms of the latter as a sort of **default** interpretation, as in the case of a dependent name where the lookup can’t even happen during parsing.  We then unconditionally call it a *qualified-id* that in some cases “is considered to denote a type”.

Comment: For the list in [basic.lookup.qual#general-2.4], it's used to describes in which components these names in which components are called qualified names. If ascribe a `simple-type-specifier`  to `qualified-id` just because a particular qualified-id has the same form with the `simple-type-specifier`, why not use the `qualified-id` to replace the `qualified-namespace-specifier` on the same way? Since it's the form `nested-name-specifier opt namespace-name` where `namespace-name` can be designated by an `identifier` eventually, which can also be denoted by a particular `qualified-id`.

Comment: @jackX: We can trivially distinguish those by checking for a following `::`.  The interplay between lookup and parsing is lamentably complicated.

Comment: Assume given this code `Name0::Name1 v;`, we could recognize `Name0::Name1 v` is not a valid expression regardless whether `Name0::Name1` denotes type. Consider `Name0` is not a dependent type.  That means, `Name0::Name1` is a `type-specifier`(decl-specifier) and the whole code is a declaration. The grammars of the `type-specifier`  are not designated by `qualified-id` at all as per the whole grammar tree of [type-specifier](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type). as far a now, lookup is not required apply here to determine what's the kind of grammar. In my humble opinion.

Comment: In other words, given a code `struct A{using type = int;}; A::type variable;` Consider this snippet, whether the name `type` is a qualified name? I would say I don't know whether it is when we examine it by using [basic.lookup.qual#general-2.4]. My reason is `A::type variable;` is a declaration where `A::type` is the component of  `decl-specifier`, we cannot find any syntax in the grammar tree of `decl-specifier` that matches the stuff designated in the list of [basic.lookup.qual#general-2.4]

Comment: @jackX: I already said this *could* be considered a defect.  But the case of `A::B * v;` **is** grammatically ambiguous, so obviously something has to happen there that might as well happen in general.

Comment: Agree `A::B * v;` is an ambiguous grammar(whether the statement is an expression or declaration, it's determined by what `A::B` is).(continued)

Comment: In my humble opinion, Could we use `qualified name` to replace `qualified-id` in [temp.res#general-5](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#general-5), since before lookup performs for `B` in a dependent context `A`(until `A` is known), we indeed don't know what `A::B` is(as you said). It can be either a simple-type-specifier or be a qualified-id(determined by the declaration found). However, use `qualified-id` to cover other things which are not be `qualified-id` itself(after performing actual lookup) is a bit of contradiction, similar to this question.